# Updating toolbar button state MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, toolbar

I have a dialog in MFC application, which is having menu-bar. Now I have created a toolbar in that dialog using the same command ID which is in the menu-bar.

I use to update the menu-item's state and makes it enable/disable as per some check in `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`, When I clicks on the menu. But for toolbar I didn't gets these calls to update it's state, If it should be enabled/disabled.

Moreover I didn't have any notification when the test fails and I to disable the item.

Is there some alternative for doing this?

Thanks

call to `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` is only coming when I click on the toolbar button.

Answer (score 1):

Use MFC in a dialog can be frustrating.

I suggest you disable the toolbar button directly when changing state to the variable that will enable / disable the menu:

```
void CtestDlg::OnBnClickedButton_DisableSomeControls()
{
command_menu_1 = !command_menu_1;
m_ToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().EnableButton(ID_COMMAND_TEST, command_menu_1);
}
```

is not very elegant, but it works!

Comment: This it feels same to me. Even in my case the dialog is modal-less, So even I am not able to do that using KICKIDLE thing, as this was the first time I am using IDLE time thing.

Moreover it a legacy code, and there is not just a single variable whose update disable/enable the toolbars' button, but there is lot of checks.